# samba-tool tool missing on Centos8 after samba412 package install

Tags: centos, samba4

Cant find samba-tool on Centos8 after samba412 package install...

dnf cant find it as well.

```
dnf provides samba-tool
Error: No Matches found
```

What's more, there is no

```
/usr/local/samba/bin
```

folder ...

Do I miss something?

Installed packages:

```
dnf list installed | grep samba

centos-release-samba412.noarch       1.0-1.el8                                  
libsmbclient.x86_64                  4.12.10-2.el8                              
libwbclient.x86_64                   4.12.10-2.el8                              
samba.x86_64                         4.12.10-2.el8                              
samba-client.x86_64                  4.12.10-2.el8                              
samba-client-libs.x86_64             4.12.10-2.el8                              
samba-common.noarch                  4.12.10-2.el8                              
samba-common-libs.x86_64             4.12.10-2.el8                              
samba-common-tools.x86_64            4.12.10-2.el8                              
samba-libs.x86_64                    4.12.10-2.el8                              
samba-vfs-glusterfs.x86_64           4.12.10-2.el8
```

Answer (score 0):

This tool is not available on RHEL or CentOS because Red Hat does not support running Samba as an Active Directory domain controller. It does not even ship the `samba-dc` package, in which `samba-tool` would otherwise be located.

You can find this tool and this package in Fedora, or in other Linux distributions.

Comment: Thanks .. So have to build it myself :) You know why now.

Comment: Not so easy "Samba AD DC and --enable-selftest requires lmdb 0.9.16 or later"

Comment: @PaulPaku Have you considered using Windows as your Active Directory domain controller?

Comment: Its customer choice not mine. But ADC on S4 works well... My problem is files sharing now.